# API command works locally but doesnt work via heroku

Tags: python, api, heroku, hosting, heroku-api

I am working on an API and made a command with that however, It doesn't work when I host it on heroku. This is not case when I try to run it locally. What should I do? Should I add something to heroku for it to be able to work with my api?

If you need my code is here:

```
@bot.command()
async def doviz(ctx):

    results = requests.get('https://api.genelpara.com/embed/doviz.json').json()
    content = results['USD']['satis']
    EUR = results['EUR']['satis']
    GBP = results['GBP']['satis']
    
    embed = discord.Embed(title="Kur Fiyatları", description="Empty")
   
    embed.add_field(name="USD: ", value=f"{content}")
    embed.add_field(name="EUR: ", value=f"{EUR}")
    embed.add_field(name="GBP: ", value=f"{GBP}")

    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Comment: When you say "it doesn't work", what exactly is the behavior you're seeing?

Comment: The sad part is nothing happens

Comment: You can add some logging and that may help to find where it "stops working".

Comment: Thank you I will try that

Answer (score 0):

if in the future someone will have same problem I fixed it.

Problem was the API I used. Looks like owner of the API decided to put a protection to it. So I simply used another API